# full resolution (MacBook Pro)

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution

Sorry in advance, but how do you set the max resolution in Big Sur?
I have a MBP 16 2019, the max resolution is supposed to be 3072 x 1920 but even with my secondary monitor disabled, I only get 2048x1280 max

do you need to use a third party app for that?

[image: screen resolution]

Comment: third party app seems to do the trick alright.

Comment: I'd change that "Extended Display" setting back to whatever the default is, and put it back to "Default for Display". Changing the Retina Scaling doesn't change the actual resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Display Menu](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/display-menu/id549083868?mt=12) on my **MacBook Pro** to set a resolution that is higher than what is shown in: **System Preferences** > **Displays**

There is also [displayplacer](https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer), which is a **macOS** *command line utility* to configure multi-display resolutions and arrangements.